# resize image on mouseover jquery masonry

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get each image to slightly increase in size on mouseover, then decrease on mouseout on jquery masonry app. However, each image is a different size. How can I apply this effect with javascript so that each image proportionally enlarges and goes back to normal?

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"105%",width:"105%"},"fast");
    });
    $(".box").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"100%",width:"100%"},"fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: please do not bold your whole question, it is unneeded

Answer (score 0):

use the addition/subtraction modifiers in the height/width settings

code below will add/subtract 20 pixels on mouseover/out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"+=20",width:"+=20"},"fast");
    });
    $(".box").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"-=20",width:"-=20"},"fast");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Scp8Q/)